# How do I get token name, symbol, and logo?

Tags: metaplex, token, metadata

Given a token, how do I determine the token's name, symbol, and logo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPL-Token's name, symbol, logo, and more can be retrieved today the following way:

1. Get associated Metaplex Metadata Account to check for Metadata
2. If no metadata exists, check legacy token-list from `@solana/spl-token-registry`

This means that first priority should be Metaplex Metadata, then `@solana/spl-token-registry`

Solflare's [Unified Token List](https://github.com/solflare-wallet/utl-aggregator) does this automatically if you want to use their source code.

Comment: the link above is for the token aggregator. Here's the link for the actual fetching of metadata https://github.com/solflare-wallet/utl-sdk