# Get Token Metadata (decimals,symbol,name...)

Tags: spl-token, token, jsonrpc-api

I'm looking to query token metadata by looking up the token address(pubkey or mint). Specifically looking for data around the `name`, `symbol`, and `decimals`. Is there an RPC method for this?

How does [SolScan](https://public-api.solscan.io/docs/#/Token/get_token_meta) do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

SPL-Token's name, symbol, logo, and more can be retrieved today the following way:

1. Get associated Metaplex Metadata Account to check for Metadata
2. If no metadata exists, check legacy token-list from `@solana/spl-token-registry`

This means that first priority should be Metaplex Metadata, then `@solana/spl-token-registry`

Solflare's [Unified Token List](https://github.com/solflare-wallet/utl-aggregator) does this automatically if you want to use their source code.

from [How do I get token name, symbol, and logo?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/218/how-do-i-get-token-name-symbol-and-logo)

---

**JSON RPC API**

use `getAccountInfo` and make sure to add `jsonParsed`

```
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getAccountInfo",
    "params": [
      "4fYNw3dojWmQ4dXtSGE9epjRGy9pFSx62YypT7avPYvA",
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed"
      }
    ]
  }
'
```

**@solana/web3.js**

use `connection.getParsedAccountInfo`

```
let mint = await connection.getParsedAccountInfo(
    new PublicKey('3MoHgE6bJ2Ak1tEvTt5SVgSN2oXiwt6Gk5s6wbBxdmmN')
)

// all the token data is here
console.log(mint.value.data.parsed)
```